# unable to connect from hibernate 5 to mysql 5.7

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, connection-string

I am trying to learn hibernate and wrote some basic code to connect MySQL database on my laptop, but I get the below error.

```
Oct 02, 2018 5:28:51 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.6.Final}
Oct 02, 2018 5:28:51 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Oct 02, 2018 5:28:52 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final}
Oct 02, 2018 5:28:55 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Oct 02, 2018 5:28:55 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/schoolsaasdb]
Oct 02, 2018 5:28:55 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
Oct 02, 2018 5:28:55 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
Oct 02, 2018 5:28:55 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 1 (min=1)
Tue Oct 02 05:28:56 BST 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Oct 02, 2018 5:28:56 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
Hibernate: drop table if exists UserDetails
Oct 02, 2018 5:28:57 AM org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl getIsolatedConnection
INFO: HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@32639b12] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.
Hibernate: create table UserDetails (userId integer not null, userName varchar(100) not null, primary key (userId)) type=MyISAM
Oct 02, 2018 5:28:58 AM org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl getIsolatedConnection
INFO: HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@4f7c0be3] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.
Oct 02, 2018 5:28:58 AM org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl handleException
WARN: GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "create table UserDetails (userId integer not null, userName varchar(100) not null, primary key (userId)) type=MyISAM" via JDBC Statement
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table UserDetails (userId integer not null, userName varchar(100) not null, primary key (userId)) type=MyISAM" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlString(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:440)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:424)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.createFromMetadata(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:315)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.performCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:166)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:310)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:467)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:708)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
    at home.purojit.hibernate.HibernateTest.main(HibernateTest.java:15)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'type=MyISAM' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:944)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3976)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3912)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2530)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2683)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2482)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2440)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:845)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:745)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54)
    ... 13 more
```

**My analysis so far**

To debug into the issue, I have set SHOW_SQL property in the hibernate.cfg.xml to true         so that I could log the SQL statement that the program is trying to generate and connect.

To my observation, though I have not mentioned **type=MyISAM** in my data base connection string jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/schoolsaasdb

hibernate tries to append it to the connection string.

**create table UserDetails (userId integer not null, userName varchar(100) not null, primary key (userId)) type=MyISAM**

when I try to copy the SQL statement and paste in the MySQL command prompt, I get the error as well.

How do I remove the **type=MyISAM** from the connection string ?

hibernate.cfg.xml is below

```
<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/schoolsaasdb</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">password</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

        <mapping resource ="entityDetails.hbm.xml"/>

    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

Below is my HibernateTest.java file

```
package home.purojit.hibernate;

import org.hibernate.AnnotationException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class HibernateTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UserDetails user = new UserDetails();
        user.setUserId(1);
        user.setUserName("HibernateUser");

        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(user);
        session.getTransaction().commit();

    }

}
```

Comment: try changing the dialect to `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57InnoDBDialect`, or the MyISAM equivalent if you don't want InnoDB

Comment: I agree with @Kartik try select a dialect that inherits from [MySQL5Dialect](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/MySQL5Dialect.html) and not the default MySQLDialect, which targets MySQL prior to version 5.x.